# to get URL address

Tags: java, url

how to get URL address while every time page is refreshed in java..?
i'm doing projects which requires URL(domain name ) while every ti e page is refreshed..!!

Comment: are you running the same pages on multiple URLs?

Answer (score 1):

user `request` object to obtain url

```
// Getting servlet request URL

String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();

// Getting servlet request query string.

String queryString = request.getQueryString();



// Getting request information without the hostname.

String uri = request.getRequestURI();
```